# how config aeron channel by udp multicast, all subs can receive messages?

Tags: multicast, aeron

I am trying to run a Basic Publisher/Subscriber pair on the same Multicast/Port.
I want to know how config channel for udp multicast, special the "interface" paramter, all subs can receive messages from pub?

I have three matchines, I want to test aeron by udp multicast type,
three matchines in one local network(lan),

pub matchineA ip 192.168.31.100,

sub1 matchineB ip 192.168.31.120,

sub2 matchineC ip 192.168.31.121,

my test case is:

pub: final String channel = "aeron:udp?endpoint=192.168.31.120:40456|interface=192.168.31.0/24|ttl=16";

sub1: final String channel = "aeron:udp?endpoint=192.168.31.120:40456|interface=192.168.31.0/24|ttl=16";

sub2: final String channel = "aeron:udp?endpoint=192.168.31.121:40456|interface=192.168.31.0/24|ttl=16";

but only sub1 can receive all messages, sub2 can not receive any messages.
I guess the "interface" paramter config may be not right.

I want to know how config channel udp multicast all subs can receive all messages?
thank you!

Comment: The IP addresses looks weird on pub and sub1 should they have the same endpoint address? and if so why is sub2 diffrent?

Answer (score 0):

endpoint config udp multicast ip 224.0.1.1 is test pass。

pub: final String channel = "aeron:udp?endpoint=224.0.1.1:40456|interface=192.168.31.100|ttl=16";

sub1: final String channel = "aeron:udp?endpoint=224.0.1.1:40456|interface=192.168.31.120|ttl=16";

sub2: final String channel = "aeron:udp?endpoint=224.0.1.1:40456|interface=192.168.31.121|ttl=16";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).